# how to make an anchor not exceed the table cell width?

Tags: html, css

My issue is that my anchor exceed table cell on iphone 5 display.

I have this as a style for the cell `white-space: nowrap;`

For the anchor I just have a background color : `background: #f88e1e;`

Could you advice please ?

```
<table class="subscriptionTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="feature"></th>
            <th class="free">free</th>
            <th class="middle">silver</th>
            <th class="top">gold</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="feature"><a href="somelink"></a>linktarget</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><span class="icon-tick"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="feature"><a href="somelink"></a>linktarget</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><span class="icon-tick"></span></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="feature"></td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <a class="someClass" href="somelink">Free trial</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've succeeded to let the text be on one line by adding `white-space: nowrap`
But now the anchor width exceed the cell width. The anchor must stay inside...

Comment: could you please include your code and some context? It's impossible to give you an answer between (literally) millions of possibilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether `display:table-cell` (CSS) or actual HTML tables, you can't prevent the immediate contents of a table cell from wrapping. They will always expand to fit the content. 
If you want to adjust the contents inside a `display: table-cell`, you'll need to wrap it in another container element and set a different display type (block/table etc).